# Why is my UI scrolling up on the iPhone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iphone

I'm creating a fairly simple JavaScript app that uses MVC and steps the user through a series of screens using jQuery to `.show()` and `.hide()` the elements necessary to each view. Works great in the browser and on an iPad, but on the iPhone the 4th view shows up with the screen scrolled down so that the top bar is invisible. Here are the views

1. Select workout
2. Enter Weight
3. Display table
4. Enter Weight <-- here is the problem
5. Display Table
6. ...

I have tried to `.remove();` some of the elements, and I've tried `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`, but neither seems to help. Check out the app (problem shows up on iPhone, not tested on other small screens): http://alesh.com/projects/workout/

Here is the whole hairy mess of code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>WorkoutCalc</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <style>
      * {
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
      }
      body {
        font-size: 1.4em;
      }


      body, textarea, input {
          font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
          background-color: #fff;
          /*background-color: #cfc;*/
      }
      strong, b, h1 {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      }
      #wrapper {
        max-width: 800px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
      }
      form {
          padding-top: 50px;
          padding-bottom: 20px;
      }
      input {
          /*border: none;*/
          text-align: right;
          font-size: 1.2em;
          width: 3em; // don't need this if input is text, only for number
      }
      input:focus {
        outline: none;
      }

      table, #weightReps, #weightSelect {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      td {
        padding: 0 20px;
      }
      td:nth-child(2) {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.6em;
        background-color: #ff0;
      }
      tr {
        background-color: #ddd;
      }
      tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 0;
      }
      tr:nth-child(even) > td:nth-child(2) {
        background-color: #dd0;
      }
      tr:first-child {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        /*font-size: .9em;*/
      }
      tr:first-child > td:nth-child(2) {
        background-color: #330;
        color: #ff0;
      }

      #header {
        background-color: #009;
        color: #fff;
      }

      h1 {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      #status {
        float:right;
        margin: 18px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1.6em;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 1.8em;
      }
      table {
        font-size: 1.4em;
      }
      #selectWorkout, #workout {
        margin-top: 50px;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #weigthSelect {
        /*display: inline-block;*/
      }
      #weightSelect, #weightReps, #doneExercise {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left:  auto;
      }
      .button {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        /*display: inline-block;*/
        background-color:#009;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 20px 30px;
        margin: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #doneButton {
        background-color: #090;
        padding: 50px 30px;
        border-radius: 100px;
      }
      .wide-button {
        display: block;
      }  

      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        body {
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        #selectWorkout, #workout {
          margin-top: 10px;
        }
        #header {
          font-size: .8em;
        }
      }

  </style>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>

    var model = {
      // currentWorkout: null,
      // currentExercise: 'sq',
      // workWeight: 230,
      currentExerciseWeights: [],
      storeExercise: [],
      // currentExerciseSets: [],
      // currentExerciseReps: [],

      calculateSets: function() {
        console.log('calculateSets');
        switch(this.currentExercise) {
          case 'sq':
            this.currentExerciseSets = [2, 1, 1, 1, 3];
            this.currentExerciseReps = [5, 5, 3, 2, 5];
            this.currentExerciseWeights[0] = 45;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[1] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .08) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[2] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .12) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[3] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .16) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[4] = this.workWeight;
            break;
          case 'bp':
            this.currentExerciseSets = [2, 1, 1, 1, 3];
            this.currentExerciseReps = [5, 5, 3, 2, 5];
            this.currentExerciseWeights[0] = 45;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[1] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .1) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[2] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .14) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[3] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .18) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[4] = this.workWeight;
            break;
          case 'dl':
            this.currentExerciseSets = [2, 1, 1, 1];
            this.currentExerciseReps = [5, 3, 2, 5];
            this.currentExerciseWeights = [];
            this.currentExerciseWeights[0] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .08) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[1] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .12) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[2] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .17) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[3] = this.workWeight;
            break;
          case 'sp':
            this.currentExerciseSets = [2, 1, 1, 1, 3];
            this.currentExerciseReps = [5, 5, 3, 2, 5];
            this.currentExerciseWeights[0] = 45;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[1] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .11) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[2] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .14) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[3] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .17) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[4] = this.workWeight;
            break;
          case 'pc':
            this.currentExerciseSets = [2, 1, 1, 1, 5];
            this.currentExerciseReps = [5, 5, 3, 2, 3];
            this.currentExerciseWeights[0] = 45;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[1] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .11) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[2] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .14) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[3] = Math.floor(this.workWeight * .17) * 5;
            this.currentExerciseWeights[4] = this.workWeight;
            break;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < this.currentExerciseWeights.length; i ++) {
          if (this.currentExerciseWeights[i] < 45) {
            this.currentExerciseWeights[i] = 45;
          }
        }
        view.workoutView();
      },

      currentExerciseName: function() {
        switch (this.currentExercise) {
          case 'sq': return 'Squat';
          case 'bp': return 'Bench Press';
          case 'dl': return 'Deadlift';
          case 'sp': return 'Press';
          case 'pc': return "Power Clean";
        }
      },

      nextExercise: function() {
        if (this.currentWorkout == 'sqBpDl') {
          switch (this.currentExercise) {
            case 'sq': 
              this.currentExercise = 'bp';
              break;
            case 'bp':
              this.currentExercise = 'dl';
              break;
            case 'dl':
              this.currentExercise = 'done';
          }
        } else {
          switch (this.currentExercise) {
            case 'sq': 
              this.currentExercise = 'sp';
              break;
            case 'sp':
              this.currentExercise = 'pc';
              break;
            case 'pc':
              this.currentExercise = 'done';
          }
        }
      }

    }     // end of model

    var view = {

      workoutSelectView: function() {
        $('#workout').hide();
        $('#selectWorkout').show();
        $('#doneExercise').hide();
        $('#doneWorkout').hide();
      },

      weightInputView: function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0); //resets the view on iPhone
        $('#selectWorkout').hide();
        $('#workout').show();
        $('#weightSelect').show();
        $('#weightInput').focus();
        $('#weightReps').hide();
        $('#doneExercise').hide();
        $('#status').html(model.currentExerciseName());
      },

      workoutView: function() {
        $('#weightInput').blur();
        var setsTable = $('<table id="weightRepsTable"><tr><td>Sets</td><td>Weight</td><td>Reps</td></tr></table>');
        for (var i = 0; i < model.currentExerciseSets.length; i ++) {
          setsTable.append($('<tr><td>' + 
            model.currentExerciseSets[i] + '</td><td>' + 
            model.currentExerciseWeights[i] + '</td><td>' + 
            model.currentExerciseReps[i] + '</td></tr>'));
        }
        $('#weightReps').html(setsTable).show();
        $('#weightSelect').hide();
        $('#doneExercise').show();
      },

      doneWorkoutView: function() {
        $('#selectWorkout').hide();
        $('#workout').hide();
        $('#weightSelect').hide();
        $('#weightReps').hide();
        $('#doneExercise').hide();
        $('#status').hide();
        $('#doneWorkout').show();
        console.log(model.storeExercise);
      }

    }

    var controller = {

      initializeEvents: function() {

        // workout select screen

        $('#sqBpDl').click(function() {
          model.currentWorkout = 'sqBpDl';
          model.currentExercise = 'sq';
          controller.doWorkout();
        });
        $('#sqSpPc').click(function() {
          model.currentWorkout = 'sqSpPc';
          model.currentExercise = 'sq';
          controller.doWorkout();
        });

        // weight entry screen

        $('#calculateWeightsButton').click(function() {
          var weight = $('#weightInput').val();
          console.log(weight);
          if (weight > 0 && weight < 2000) {
            model.workWeight = weight;
            $('#weightInput').val(null);
            model.calculateSets();
          }
        });

        // weight display screen

        $('#doneButton').click(function() {
          model.storeExercise.push({ 
            exercise: model.currentExercise,
            weight: model.workWeight,
            complete: model.weightOk
          });
          model.nextExercise();
          if (model.currentExercise == 'done') {
            view.doneWorkoutView();
          } else {
            view.weightInputView();
          }
        });

        $('#backButton').click(function() {
          $('#weightInput').val(model.workWeight);
          view.weightInputView();
        });

        // universal

        // hitting the 'return' key will trigger whichever button has
        // the class 'default-button' AND is visible
        $(window).keypress(function (event) {
          if (event.which == 13) {
            $('.default-button:visible').click(); 
          }
        });
      },

      doWorkout: function() {
        view.weightInputView();
      },

      selectWorkout: function() {
        view.workoutSelectView();
      }

    }

    $(function() {

      var test = false;
      if (test) {

        controller.initializeEvents();
        $('#doneWorkout').hide();
        model.currentWorkout = 'sqBpDl';
        model.currentExercise = 'sq';
        controller.doWorkout();
        model.workWeight = 240;
        model.calculateSets();

      } else {

        controller.initializeEvents();
        controller.selectWorkout();

      }

    });

  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="status"></div>
    <h1>Warmup Calc</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="selectWorkout">
      <div class="wide-button button" id="sqBpDl">Squat &middot; Bench Press &middot; Deadlift</div>
      <div class="wide-button button" id="sqSpPc">Squat &middot; Press &middot; Power Clean</div>
    </div>
    <div id="workout">
      <div id="weightSelect">
        <p>
          <input id="weightInput" size="5" step="5" min="45" max="2000"type="number" > lbs. 
        </p>
        <div class="button default-button" id="calculateWeightsButton">GO</div>
      </div>
      <div id="weightReps"></div>
      <div id="doneExercise">
        <div class="button" id="backButton">&lt; BACK</div>
        <div class="button default-button" id="doneButton">DONE</div>
        <!-- <div class="button" id="doneOuchButton">DONE: !!</div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="doneWorkout">
      <p>Done!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you refine your example to a small generic one? say, just of the dialog (html, css) and calculation of where the issue is? it'll make it a whole lot easier for readers to help you out.

Comment: @BIW, I'd like to try, but I'm confused where to begin. This problem happens half-way through the program's execution, and I have no idea which components are causing it. Usually I'm pretty good at troubleshooting by eliminating blocks of stuff until the problem bit becomes apparent, I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of the thing to look for.

Comment: No worries at all buddy, atleast you've made an attempt thats all that matters. I'll have a gander.

Comment: is the weight input for the weight of the 'weights' or the weight of the person? and do you mean scrolling up asin the weight UI is moving up when you query for an iphone? or when scrolling with your finger you have issues?

Comment: Weight of the exercise. (If you're digging through my code, first sorry, second, focus on the `var = view` section. I'm pretty sure the problem is somehow happening with the code juggling the various sections between shown and hidden...) @BIW

Comment: [This might help](http://alesh.com/projects/workout/iphone-example.png) -- the screen on the left is the input in step #2, the right is step #4, before doing anything on the screen. @BIW